# HDFS. How to free 1 particular disk

Tags: disk-space-utilization, hadoop, hdfs

I have cluster with 3 servers. 2 of them have 2 TB disks and another one have 500 Gb SSD. I am trying to use balancer, but I still get 70% of usage on 2TB disks and 99% on 500Gb due to non-dfs files. Replication coefficient=2. Is it possible to free my 500 Gb disk with balancer or somehow else?

Answer (score 0):

So, I've found the following solution: increase "Reserved Space for Non DFS Use" parameter to 100 Gb. Now HDFS estimates disk usage the way more correctly and i can use balancer to solve my issue